# Modifying the css of a widget C++ GTK

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to edit the css of a tree view model (list store), I have set everything up using this code and it works perfectly:

```
auto css_provider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
css_provider->load_from_path("style.css");

Gtk::StyleContext::add_provider_for_screen
                    (Gdk::Screen::get_default(), css_provider, 
                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

This code successfully loads in the css file and I can change certain properties of the treeview, ive tested padding and that works fine, it applies padding to each row in the liststore:

```
treeview.view {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

or

```
treeview * {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

But if I try to reference the name of the treeview, it doesn't work (no errors or warnings):

```
#m_TreeView {           /* or m_TreeView.view */
    padding: 20px;
}
```

My main goal is to apply a margin between each row, but this also doesn't seem to work (no errors or warnings), I want to apply a margin to each row but reference the specific name of the tree view as I would have multiple tree views in my application:

```
treeview.view {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Tried to access the rows and tried to access the list stores children (*):

```
treeview row {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

+

```
liststore * {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But if I try to reference the name of the treeview, it doesn't work (no errors or warnings):

The name you need is not the variable name. To give a name for CSS styling, you can set it by calling

```c
void Gtk::Widget::set_name  (   const Glib::ustring &   name    )
```

Comment: That works great for a widget such as a tree view but doesnt seem to work for a liststore which in my program is declared as "Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> m_List;" also the margin css property doesnt seem to work with the rows in the ListStore but padding does

Comment: You don't set css style for ListStore, because it's meant to be used to store data only. The data it stored can be represented in a Treeview.  So do css styling in Treeview, not ListStore.

Comment: ahh brilliant thank you, with the margin when I set it for the TreeViews children it adds a margin to the column names but not actually to the rows, but when I change it from margin to padding, padding is applied to both the column names and the rows

Comment: tried a bit of a hack by adding a border and setting border-spacing but I get an error when I try this

Comment: column names? Do you mean header? I tested it on my own computer, padding doesn't affect header. You can see how gtk official theme Adwaita css, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/raw/gtk-3-24/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css. There is some treeview sections inside.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant the header, yeah I just tested on mine and it works for the rows, but with the margin properties that only works for the headers and not the rows

Comment: Can you try `treeview rubberband { padding : 20px; }`?The header doesn't seem to be affected by any setting I do. Perhaps because we're using different gtk or gnome version.

Comment: I want the header to be that same what I want is to add a margin to each row in the treeview